# FreeDiskSpaceFailed: How to force re-check, instead of waiting for self-healing?

Tags: kubernetes

I had `FreeDiskSpaceFailed` on one of my K8s nodes.

I fixed this by resizing the logical volume.

I don't want to wait until K8s has discovered that there is enough space now.

Is there a way to trigger K8s, so that the disk space gets checked again?

Comment: I would _guess_ restarting `kubelet.service` will go through all its normal initialization checks, which likely includes free disk checking

Comment: Hi guettli, did the instructions from comment above solve your issue?

Comment: @PiotrMalec I don't know. The self-healing of K8s detected after some minutes that there is enough space on the disk.